# Testing Spring Boot REST API

Tags: java, spring, rest, junit, spring-boot

What would be the best practice to test a Spring Boot Rest API with JUnit? Using `com.jayway.restassured.*` api or `org.springframework.boot.test.*` api?

Any know advantage or drawbacks over another?

Comment: "Best approach" is a bit subjective.  What are your concerns between them?  Try writing a test in each and see which one performs/writes better.

Comment: i would say industry common practice

Comment: I am using RestAssured for a project and am liking it. Had tried both a bit before choosing, and had felt RestAssured more convenient and closer to real-world scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Spring's test is faster as it doesn't need to spin-up a servlet container.

REST-Assured is slower, but it will test your application completely, including servlet container configuration (e.g. filter chain).

I prefer to use spring-test for unit-testing the controllers, and to do the complete functional regression test (using other tools) on a deployed version as the last step of my nightly build.

Comment: Since i am using spring boot, there is no need to start a servlet container for Rest-Assured also

Comment: Well, you don't need to start it manually, but it's still using Spring Boot's embedded servlet container which takes some time to start

Answer (score 0):

If the version of Spring Boot you are using is later than `1.4.0 RC1`, the module - `spring-boot-test` will be automatically added into your dependencies.

And Spring already comes with great support for writing integration tests leveraging the `spring-boot-test` module.

So I recommend you to just use the native API of Spring framework for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use gherkin/cucumber to test your apis => https://github.com/RedFroggy/spring-cucumber-rest-api